# Softlayer get customer list from master brand account

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

How I can get customer list of master brand account using python.

I tried like this:

```
import Softlayer
client = Sotlayer.Client(api_key='xxxxx',username='xxxxxxx')
brand_id ='xxxxx'
brand_users  = client['Brand'].getUsers(id=brand_id)
```

I not able get all customer list

Comment: Can you make it a little more clear on what is the master brand here and softlayer relation to it. Also, I think there is a typo in Sotlayer.Clinet(api_key='xxxxx',username='xxxxxxx'). It should be Softlayer.Client().

Comment: @ArjunSingh type error no problem. i need all customers under master brand account

Comment: @Robert fix the typo in your code

Comment: get all customers form master brand account any ideas ???/

Comment: not able to get all customer list, but what happens? is there an error? only get a partial list or what?

Comment: no errors.get corresponding brand account details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
'''
Get owned account

The script retrieves all the owned accounts for an arbitrary brand,
the script makes a call to getOwnedBrands() method to retrieve
the brands where the account belongs, then it calls the getAllOwnedAccounts()
method to get the owned accounts for every brand.

Important manual pages
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getOwnedBrands
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getAllOwnedAccounts
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Brand
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Brand

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
'''
import SoftLayer.API

USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

accountService = client['SoftLayer_Account']
brandService = client['SoftLayer_Brand']

# Getting the brands
brands = accountService.getOwnedBrands()
for brand in brands:
    brandId = brand['id']
    # Getting the owned Accounts
    accounts = brandService.getAllOwnedAccounts(id=brandId)
    for account in accounts:
        print(account['companyName'])
```